# react-select error: str.replace is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, relayjs

I am trying to implement react-select in my project. 
My code is here: https://gist.github.com/BikalNepal/9172b3161abfa545cc5748055c6584c6

The data for search is being fetched using graphql and relay from a backend nodejs server, when I type into the box, it fetches the data properly but when I click on the data, I get the following errors:

```
Option selected: {value: "stark@gmail.com", label: "rickon"}// Selected data is okay
Error:
react-select.esm.js?acac:1224 Uncaught TypeError: str.replace is not a function
    at trimString (react-select.esm.js?acac:1224)
    at Object.eval [as filterOption] (react-select.esm.js?acac:1246)
    at Select.filterOption (react-select.esm.js?acac:3952)
    at toOption (react-select.esm.js?acac:4038)
    at options.reduce.render (react-select.esm.js?acac:4092)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Select.buildMenuOptions (react-select.esm.js?acac:4071)
    at Select.componentWillReceiveProps (react-select.esm.js?acac:3575)
    at callComponentWillReceiveProps (react-dom.development.js?cada:11395)
    at updateClassInstance (react-dom.development.js?cada:11605)
trimString @ react-select.esm.js?acac:1224
(anonymous) @ react-select.esm.js?acac:1246
filterOption @ react-select.esm.js?acac:3952
toOption @ react-select.esm.js?acac:4038
options.reduce.render @ react-select.esm.js?acac:4092
buildMenuOptions @ react-select.esm.js?acac:4071
componentWillReceiveProps @ react-select.esm.js?acac:3575
callComponentWillReceiveProps @ react-dom.development.js?cada:11395
updateClassInstance @ react-dom.development.js?cada:11605
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js?cada:14648
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?cada:15598
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?cada:19266
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js?cada:19306
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?cada:149
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?cada:199
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?cada:256
replayUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?cada:18532
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js?cada:19422
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?cada:20296
performWork @ react-dom.development.js?cada:20208
performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js?cada:20182
interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js?cada:20449
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js?cada:2170
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js?cada:4882
react-dom.development.js?cada:17071 

The above error occurred in the <Select> component:
    in Select (created by StateManager)
    in StateManager (created by CustomerSearch)
    in div (created by FormGroup)
    in FormGroup (created by CustomerSearch)
    in div (created by Col)
    in Col (created by CustomerSearch)
    in div (created by CustomerSearch)
    in CustomerSearch (created by Relay(CustomerSearch))
    in Relay(CustomerSearch) (created by ReactRelayQueryRenderer)
    in ReactRelayQueryRenderer (created by CustomerSearchPage)
    in div (created by CustomerSearchPage)
    in div (created by CustomerSearchPage)
    in CustomerSearchPage (created by ProductPerformance)
    in div (created by Row)
    in Row (created by ProductPerformance)
    in div (created by Container)
    in Container (created by ProductPerformance)
    in div (created by ProductPerformance)
    in ProductPerformance (created by Relay(ProductPerformance))
    in Relay(ProductPerformance) (created by ReactRelayQueryRenderer)
    in ReactRelayQueryRenderer (created by ProductPerformancePage)
    in div (created by ProductPerformancePage)
    in div (created by ProductPerformancePage)
    in ProductPerformancePage (created by Route)
    in Route (created by RoutePage)
    in div (created by RoutePage)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (created by RoutePage)
    in RoutePage (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Have you checked your `options` and `value` state when the error happens?

Answer (score 0):

Here you're making a reference to an `event` constant that you never declare. Below your code fixed. See on props `onInputChange` and `onKeyDown` you have to call `event` before sending it.

```
 <Select
   value={selectedOption}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   options={this.state.options}
   // onKeyDown={event => this.handleRefetch(event)}
   onInputChange={event => this.handleInput(event)}
   inputValue={this.state.value}
 />
```

Comment: It is not solving the issue.